# Как распарсить конструкцию json в react native

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, arraylist, react-native

Не давно начал изучение react native.
И столкнулся с проблемой.
Пытаюсь распарсить https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist
И получить ссылки на картинки из раздела Data
Сам раздел я получил

```
dataImages: Array(responseJson.Data)
console.log(this.state.dataImages[0])
```

Выглядит так:

```
"42": {
"Id": "4321",
"Url": "/coins/42/overview",
"ImageUrl": "/media/12318415/42.png",
"Name": "42",
"Symbol": "42",
"CoinName": "42 Coin",
"FullName": "42 Coin (42)",
"Algorithm": "Scrypt",
"ProofType": "PoW/PoS",
"FullyPremined": "0",
"TotalCoinSupply": "42",
"PreMinedValue": "N/A",
"TotalCoinsFreeFloat": "N/A",
"SortOrder": "34",
"Sponsored": false
},
"300": {
"Id": "749869",
"Url": "/coins/300/overview",
"ImageUrl": "/media/27010595/300.png",
"Name": "300",
"Symbol": "300",
"CoinName": "300 token",
"FullName": "300 token (300)",
"Algorithm": "N/A",
"ProofType": "N/A",
"FullyPremined": "0",
"TotalCoinSupply": "300",
"PreMinedValue": "N/A",
"TotalCoinsFreeFloat": "N/A",
"SortOrder": "2212",
"Sponsored": false
},...
```

Не смотря на то что я добавил '[0]'
Могу получить элемент если после поставлю '.DOGE' (имя елемента)
Но нужно получить из всех элементов поле ImageUrl или Name
Подскажите пожалуйста что я не так делаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот таким вот образом я прошёлся по всем элементам

```
for (var key in this.state.dataImages) {
            if (key == coinKey) {
                urlImage = `${this.state.dataImages[key].ImageUrl}`
            }
        }
```